# Best Way To Save Multiple Credit Cards / Access iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

I have an application (currently using Core Data) that takes credit card information, sends it to my server, gets a response (i.e. authorized, denied, error, etc). If authorized, the card gets saved along with a "slot" number in a wallet. The way the server works is sort of haunting me when using core data due to the following; let me draw it out for you.

There are 5 available "slots" for credit cards.

1. //empty
2. //empty
3. //empty
4. //empty
5. //empty

When a user adds a credit card, it gets saved to a "slot" and is assigned a value 1-5 to keep track of it.

1. Card 1
2. Card 2
3. Card 3
4. //empty
5. //empty

Now the problem that's haunting me with Core Data is deleting a card. I want the number to stay the same and I want the card to stay in the same pocket, like so:

1. Card 1
2. //empty
3. Card 3
4. //empty
5. //empty

...and the next time a card is added it needs to let the server know it is going to "slot" 2. How can I achieve such tracking?

Thanks in advance.

If I was too vague (I'm hoping I wasn't) please leave a comment and I'll give details back within minutes.

**Edit: The phone doesn't actually store the credit cards, it stores the slot number. The server has the credit cards saved, and that's the reason for the slot number.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, have you considered using the Keychain to store sensitive information instead of Core Data?

Second, if you will stick to Core Data and you need to persist ordering, just add an additional attribute to the entity called "slot_id" and stick the info in there. Then tell the  server that the next card should be stored into the next first empty slot. If you are talking to the server via HTTP, you could use a POST argument to order it to store into the empty slot.

How to figure out if a slot is empty?

Use a sort descriptor to sort by slot_id. Then, compare ordering to actual natural ordering.

```
what you should encounter: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
what you encounter:        1 2 3 5 6 7
```

Obviously, 4 is missing, so as soon as you notice a discrepancy, abort the loop.

Alternatively, track the "minimum available slot" in a separate entity or in NSUserDefaults, to optimize the search algorithm. Or even track the "emptied slots" as separate entities which you then sort by their slot_ids.

Comment: Regarding the keychain, the phone doesn't actually store the credit cards, it stores the slot number. The server has the credit cards saved, and that's the reason for the slot number. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Just parse the list, when you get to one whose description is '//empty', insert the card into that slot.

Comment: Can you give more details? When doing this with Core Data I've been under the impression that it doesn't have set "slots" like an array. i.e. for three cards, it would only see three slots, etc.

Comment: See Ivan's answer below (which I'm upvoting if only because of the reminder to use the Keychain to store sensitive data)

Comment: The phone doesn't actually store the credit cards, it stores the number. The server has the credit cards saved, and that's the reason for the slot number. I edited the post.